# F#: How to apply Json.NET [JsonConstructor] attribute to primary constructor?

Tags: json, f#, json.net

I'm trying to do something in F# like the `JsonConstructorAttribute` example in the [Json.NET documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm):

```cs
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; private set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; private set; }

    public User()
    {
    }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public User(string userName, bool enabled)
    {
        UserName = userName;
        Enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

The analog in F# appears to be something like the following, but I'm getting an error on the placement of `[<JsonConstructor>]`:

```ml
[<JsonConstructor>] // ERROR! (see below)
type User (userName : string, enabled : bool) =
    member this.UserName = userName
    member this.Enabled = enabled
```

The error is

> This attribute is not valid for use on this language element

So then, how do I decorate the primary constructor with `[<JsonConstructor>]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that it's pretty easy. Target the primary constructor by placing `[<JsonConstructor>]` just before the primary constructor's parameter list:

```ml
type User [<JsonConstructor>] (userName : string, enabled : bool) =
    member this.UserName = userName
    member this.Enabled = enabled
```